# Not checking file size correctly

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io, operating-system

I wrote a simple script to move movies in my downloads directory, once they are finished downloading, to the location they need to go and have a simple question regarding it.

Maybe I'm not understanding how the `os` module is working to the current size of the file here, but it is not returning the correct size of the file. It is returning the full size of the downloaded file and not the size of the file on the hard disk as that will be the downloaded size which I need to compare against. Is there a way to fix this, or a better check to perform?

I've commented the relevant lines, and as in the comments it returns the same size after waiting 30 seconds using `time.sleep`, but the actual downloaded portion is much greater.

As noted in the comments, the file size is allocated before downloading hence why this doesn't work.

```
def check_size(file_path):
    check = False
    previous_size = os.path.getsize(file_path) # first check
    print("The current size of the movie at %s is: " %  time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"), previous_size)
    time.sleep(30)
    new_size = os.path.getsize(file_path) #30 secs later same size as first check, but downloaded size ~100 mb greater?
    print("The current size of the movie at %s is: " % time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"), new_size)
    if previous_size == new_size:
         check = True
    return check

def move_movies(source, file_extension, sub_string):
    while process_running():
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
            for a_file in filenames:
                if (a_file.endswith(file_extension) and sub_string in a_file):
                    path = dirpath + "\\" +  a_file
                    print("Checking the movie:", a_file, "for moving")
                    if check_size(path):  
                        print("Moving the movie: ", a_file)
                        shutil.move(dirpath, some destination path)
```

Comment: What program are you using to download the files?  If it knows the downloaded file size in advance (which is usually the case when downloading over the web), it's more efficient for it to allocate a file that's the right size and overwrite it with the data as it comes in, which means the size on disk will always be the same.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could memory map the file (using [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html)).  First find the last non-zero byte in the file, then check to see if any other bytes are changing after that.

If you want to see if the file is still open by another process you could use [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) (you'd need to open a subprocess to call this).  That might only work on unix-like operating systems though and I don't know if there's a windows equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to checking if the size has changed recently, you could check the modified time on the file:

```
import os,time
def getAge(path):
    """ returns the age of the file in seconds """
    return (time.time() - os.stat(path).st_mtime)
```

Comment: The only workaround I found, and which still doesn't really work, is to check the free space of the disk and that's including things that may not necessarily be the file im checking itself using `shutil.disk_usage()` or `psutil.disk_usage()`